# Sideloading of Outlook add in failed due to Unauthorized 401

Tags: node.js, npm, outlook, office365, sideloading

I am trying to make a simple add in by following microsofts official tutorial for building your first add in. I followed the instructions down to the last detail but I kept geting the same error.

The error occours after I run npm start then, I get prompted to sign in with my Microsoft account which I did. Then I get this back in my terminal:

```
Successfully registered package! (??)
```

STDERR: (×) Error: [Login] Failed to retrieve token silently. If you encounter this problem multiple times, you can delete `C:\Users\Benjamin Agic\.fx\account` and try again. invalid_scope: 70011 - [2024-02-16 15:41:20Z]: AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope 'https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/AppDefinitions.ReadWrite openid profile offline_access' does not exist. Trace ID: 25aaa001-6ef9-467f-8d63-085a14dec900 Correlation ID: a71e1aa8-fddb-4483-bbcd-af353a108f66 Timestamp: 2024-02-16 15:41:20Z - Correlation ID: a71e1aa8-fddb-4483-bbcd-af353a108f66 - Trace ID: 25aaa001-6ef9-467f-8d63-085a14dec900
(×) Error: Sideloading failed.
(×) Error: {"statusCode":401,"message":"Unauthorized"}
(×) Error: m365.UnhandledError: An unexpected error has occurred while performing the M365 task. {"stack":"Error: {"message":"Request failed with status code 401","detail":"{\"statusCode\":401,\"message\":\"Unauthorized\"}","tracingId":""}\n    at createError (C:\Users\Benjamin Agic\Desktop\Plugin\Gist the git\node_modules\@microsoft\teamsfx-cli\lib\index.js:14:300960)\n    at settle (C:\Users\Benjamin Agic\Desktop\Plugin\Gist the git\node_modules\@microsoft\teamsfx-cli\lib\index.js:14:305240)\n    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\Benjamin Agic\Desktop\Plugin\Gist the git\node_modules\@microsoft\teamsfx-cli\lib\index.js:14:290544)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:530:35)\n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)","message":"{"message":"Request failed with status code 401","detail":"{\"statusCode\":401,\"message\":\"Unauthorized\"}","tracingId":""}","config":{}}

I have outlook on my pc and I have signed microsoft account..what could be the potential issue of this?